# How can I change excerpt length of CPT loop on a post type "page"?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages

When I loop through CPT on my homepage it displays correctly, but I can't control the excerpt length.

I want to loop through 4 different CPT on my front page. The loop is working but my conditional logic for controlling the excerpt length isn't working as expected because get_post_type returns "page" and not the actual CPT.

thi is in my functions.php:

```
add_filter('excerpt_length', 'll_get_excerpt_length');

function ll_get_excerpt_length($size) {

    if (is_post_type_archive('post')) {
        return 40;
    } elseif (is_post_type_archive('podcast')) {
        return 15;
    } elseif (is_post_type_archive('review')) {
        return 5;
    } else {
        return $size;
    }
}
```

when var dumping the post type I get "page", so I do not know where or how to control the various lengths of excerpt.

I expected the excerpt length to be correct for every CPT loop on my front page.

When I add the following with print_r, I only get into the function but not into the ifs.

```
add_filter('excerpt_length', 'll_get_excerpt_length');

function ll_get_excerpt_length($size) {
   print_r(get_post_type());
    if (is_post_type_archive('post')) {
        print_r(get_post_type());
        return 40;
    } elseif (is_post_type_archive('podcast')) {
         print_r(get_post_type());
        return 15;
    } elseif (is_post_type_archive('review')) {
         print_r(get_post_type());
        return 5;
    } else {
        return $size;
    }
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Can you show your actual loop through CPTs, I suspect that's where the solution lies.

Comment: Im using elementor to design the page. So the actual loops happen within elementor logic.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this way:

```
add_filter('excerpt_length', 'll_get_excerpt_length');

function ll_get_excerpt_length( $size ) {
    if ( is_archive() ) {
        return 40;
    } elseif (is_post_type_archive('podcast')) {
        return 15;
    } elseif (is_post_type_archive('review')) {
        return 5;
    } else {
        return $size;
    }
}
```

is_post_type_archive() only returns true if it is a CPT and has_archive attribute of the CPT is set to true like this:

```
add_action( 'init', 'create_post_type' );

function create_post_type() {
  register_post_type( 'review',
    array(
      'labels' => array(
        'name' => __( 'Reviews' ),
        'singular_name' => __( 'Review' )
      ),
      'public' => true,
      'has_archive' => true, //like this
    )
  );
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: I will try this! Thank you. Will uodate tomorrow!

Comment: unfortunately it didnt change the behaviour. I am assuming it is because he doesnt know it as a post type archive if it is a loop on the front page..

Comment: Sorry, I can't understand what you want to say?

Answer (score 0):

is_post_type_archive will only return true if you are on an archive page should you not be checking is_single(), is_singular('podcast') instead?

Comment: thats my question... how can I check that on the front page ? is_singular wont return true only if Im on that specific page of that CPT?

Comment: I'm thinking maybe pre_get_posts might be the action to use (https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/pre_get_posts) if(is_front_page() && !is_main_query), sorry I'd usually code these things rather than use page builders.

Comment: I understand. totally agree, when working though in a big agency with 30 projects to go live soon, you need to use a builder and Elementor is really top :) 

Honestly I never had issues like this before, but this project was custom built a few years ago and getting to work with our builder is a bit of a pain! thanks anyway for the effort!